# onSystemUiVisibilityChange not called after screen rotation

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a fullscreen app, with the navigation bar disapearing after few seconds and reappearing on user interaction (like the Android 3d gallery video player behaviour) for Android 4.2.2 (API 17)

To achieve this, i'm using this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private View mRootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // OnCreate code ...
    mRootView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener();
    showSystemUi(false);
}

private void showSystemUi(boolean visible) {
    int flag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    if (!visible) {
    // We used the deprecated "STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN" for unbundling
        flag |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }
    mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
}

private void setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    mRootView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
            new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showSystemUi(false);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
    });
}
```

As you can see, i've been inspired by the Android API and the  android 3d gallery code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/gallery3d/app/MoviePlayer.java#MoviePlayer.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener%28%29

So, here is my problem :
This code works greatly if i don't move the device.
But if i made a screen rotation, the navigation bar will not be displayed, clicking on screen will display it, but the callback onSystemUiVisibilityChange seems to be never called (checked with debugger), so the navigation bar will never disappear. And if i rotate the screen again, it will works again. (In fact, it seems like it only works if i rotate the screen while the navigation bar is displayed)

Does anyone has an idea of where this problem comes from ?

Thx.

Comment: I finally figured out how to fix this problem.
I just have to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the AndroidManifest.xml for my activity.

The problem is, i don't really understand why. Anyone knows ?

Comment: So, i still have the problem, but not everytime. 
I can't really figured out why and how to reproduce it, it just happen when i change my screen orientation.

Comment: The reason why removing 'orientation' from the manifest file works, is  this lets your activity know you want to handle orientation changes yourself instead of Android automatically doing all the saveinstancestate, etc. for you.

Comment: The same happens to me when trying to use lights out mode. Listener is not called the first time I change visibility after a screen rotation...

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem on a 5.0 Nexus 7 but not on a 4.4 HTC One.  Anyone know how to hack around this without using configChanges?